# Quais as consequências de sair do sistema sem fechar as tabelas?

Tags: delphi

Quais as consequências de ***Sair / Encerrar*** de um sistema sem fechar as tabelas do banco de dados? Isso prejudica em alguma coisa no banco de dados?

Eu devo ou não fechar as tabelas do sistema?

```
procedure TfrmTelaPrincipal.EncerraSistema;
begin
  Beep;
  if Application.MessageBox('Deseja Realmente Encerrar o Sistema?','Pergunta',
                        MB_YESNO+MB_ICONQUESTION+MB_DEFBUTTON2) <> IDNO then
  begin
    ReciclarLixoDeSistema;
    DMGeral.tbParametros.Edit;
    DMGeral.tbParametrosNUMERO_ESTACOES_LOGADAS.AsInteger := DMGeral.tbParametrosNUMERO_ESTACOES_LOGADAS.AsInteger-1;
    DMGeral.tbParametros.Post;
    MinimizarClick(Self);
    frmTelaPrincipal.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Ps: *Eu utilizo a estrutura **cliente/servidor** sendo que o banco de dados fica no servidor e meu componente de conexão é **FireDAC***

Comment: Esta pergunta pode ter mil respostas diferente. Depende muito da estrutura utilizada (client > server > banco ou client > banco), componentes utilizados, qual banco de dados e lógica de conexão e etc ...

Comment: Realmente pode ter mais de uma consequência, não tenho todas, mas uma é que  libera o registro de sessão na memória do servidor de banco de dados, se houver muitas conexões e isso não for pensado, pode estourar a memória ram do servidor.

Comment: Eu utilizo a estrutura cliente/servidor sendo que o banco de dados fica no servidor e meu componente de conexão é FireDAC

Answer (score 1):

Não corrompe o banco, mas se alguma operação se manter ativa, pode deixar o banco com lock, "travado" para outras operações na mesma tabela/registro.

Esse tipo de comportamento varia de um banco de dados para outro, por isso é uma boa prática desalocar recursos, fechar conexões através de estruturas de proteção de recursos como o try finally

Comment: Dependendo do tipo de conexão não finalizar a tabela pode acarretar a continuidade da memoria alocada, sendo possível causar queda do sistema por exceder a disponibilidade de memoria.

Answer (score 1):

No atual sistema que estou trabalhando, licença do usuário final é feito através do controle transacional entre a aplicação e o banco de dados `Firebird`.

Ou seja, neste modelo, sabemos quantas conexões estão ativas no momento, assim a aplicação não roda se ultrapassar a quantidade de transações, é um meio barato e simples de fazer.

Então, no nosso caso, o controle transacional é muito importante.

Cada consulta que realizamos consiste em um aumento no processo do cliente lá no lado do servidor, segue...

```
DataSetCliente := 'SELECT NOME, CPF, FROM CLIENTES WHERE CODIGO > 2500'
```

Veja que agora o `DataSetCliente` esta carregado com os dados selecionados, porem, não fizemos um `fetchall`, considerando que possuímos nesta tabela 50.000 registros o banco de dados não nos entrega de imediato os 47.500 registros restantes, entregara apenas uma parcela disto.

Neste caso o processo cliente desta transação fica em standby no lado do servidor esperando ser requisitado mais dados, seja através de um `Next` ou `Last`.

Destruimos então o `DataSetCliente` no fim de seu uso:

```
DataSetCliente.Close; //Aqui ele interrompe a transação, mas não a finaliza
DataSetCliente.Free; //Agora liberamos a transação
```

A importância depende do modelo de conexão que esta utilizando, mas como comentado, é importantíssimo para o lado do Servidor que exista este controle.

Importante ressaltar que neste cenário, estamos utilizando DelphiXe10.2 e o componente para conexão é da Devrace, o FibPlus.